# variables returning null value upon switching View Controllers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables, uiviewcontroller, null, segue

Im new to programming with objective C and am working on moving data between View controllers. I am wondering if Bi-directional flow of data (variables) between ViewControllers is possible.
I can move data backwards (to the  presentingViewController / sourceViewController) however i cannot move data forward (to the presentedViewController / destinationViewController).

I have made a simple case scenario (involving strings to get a principle of the idea) of this and it involves updating a **UItextField** on the destinationViewController using a **UILabel** in the sourceViewController and vice-versa.
I CANNOT update the **UITextField** using the **UILabel**, but can update the **UILabel** using the **UITextField**.
I have made Logs of different statements to track the variable values however when I switch ViewControllers the variables Data returns to null even if they are marked as strong.

Can you please offer any guidance, its been tearing away at my mind, or am I missing something obvious? I don't get why I keep getting a (null) value (in my NSLog) when I switch ViewControllers.

- My sourceViewController / presentingViewController is named "ViewController."
- My destinationViewController / presentedViewController is named "Gears2ViewController".

I have attached my code files below:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;
- (IBAction)ExitToHere:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Gear2ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction)changeItem:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeItem:(id)sender {

    Gear2ViewController *G2VC=[[Gear2ViewController alloc] init];

    G2VC.peterSido=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.outputLabel.text];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toGear2" sender:self];

    NSLog(@"ViewController UILabel reads %@",G2VC.peterSido);
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
}

- (IBAction)ExitToHere:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender {
}

@end
```

Gears2ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface Gear2ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *peterSido;
@end
```

Gears2ViewController.m:

```
@interface Gear2ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *updatedOutput;
- (IBAction)updateOutput:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation Gear2ViewController


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"Gears2ViewController ViewDidAppear reads %@",self.peterSido);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Gears2ViewController ViewDidLoad responds %@",self.peterSido);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)updateOutput:(id)sender {

    self.peterSido = self.updatedOutput.text;
    ((ViewController *)self.presentingViewController).outputLabel.text = self.peterSido;
     NSLog(@"Gears2View Controller updating ViewController UILabel reads %@",self.peterSido);  
}

@end
```

NSLog:

```
2015-06-29 18:52:58.798 testerBeta[21735:645772] Gears2ViewController ViewDidLoad responds (null)
2015-06-29 18:52:58.799 testerBeta[21735:645772] ViewController UILabel reads I like Pie
2015-06-29 18:52:59.317 testerBeta[21735:645772] Gears2ViewController ViewDidAppear reads (null)
2015-06-29 18:53:12.651 testerBeta[21735:645772] Gears2View Controller updating ViewController UILabel reads No I dont
```

Quite Lengthy but Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: The reason why the passed value is null is because you instantiate your own Gear2 vc, set a value on your instantiated vc, then segue which instantiates a different Gear2 vc.  Your own Gear2 vc is unused, and never presented.  Meanwhile, the segue's vc property is null.  I show you how to  properly set the segue's view controller property in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass the data in `prepareForSegue:`, like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toGear2"])
    {
        Gear2ViewController *controller = (Gear2ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.peterSido = self.outputLabel.text;
    }
}
```

The reason why is that the segue instantiates the presented view controller for you, and you then set the property of the instantiated view controller which the segue will present.

To pass the data back, you can use an unwind segue, which can get the value from the presented view controller's property.

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromGear2:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    Gear2ViewController *controller = (Gear2ViewController *)segue.sourceViewController;
    self.outputLabel.text = controller.peterSido;
}
```

This is the proper way to pass data back and forth via segues.  Gear2ViewController **shouldn't** be setting properties on its presentingViewController.

**Update:**

The preferred way to test that a property isn't nil is like this:

```
if (self.peterSido)
{
    self.updatedOutput.text = self.peterSido;
}
else // No need for if test here
{
    self.updatedOutput.text = @"";
}
```

That's the long form, but the assignment and if test can be more concisely written as:

```
self.updatedOutput.text = self.peterSido ?: @"";
```

Comment: Inputting the code into the -(void) prepareForSegue method didn't work, however if I assigned the method to the button **- (IBAction) changeItem**, followed by **[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toGear2" sender:self]**, then in the destination view controller implemented the viewDidAppear method it works. Perhaps there something wrong with the -(void) prepareForSegue on my system. Thanks you saved me.

Comment: That works perfectly, way shorter than what I had written. Had come across the notation but didn't understand it, now I do. So basically                                 `if(self.peterSido=self.peterSido)`                                                                      is the same as                                                                                                 `if(self.peterSido)`                                                                                             I prefer the later, shorter and more simple. Thanks Again.

Comment: Not the same.  `if (x == x)` tests for equality, and would always be true, even for 0 == 0.  `if (x)` is shorthand for `if (x != 0)` and tests for not nil.

Comment: Thank you for the update, tried looking but couldn't actually find it explained.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare any variable as @property then you need to synthesize it in .m file .
You have declared your outputLabel as @property but you missed to synthesize it in .m file.
When you synthesize any variable then it allows you to get and set the values to it .
Do it it will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: Will try the manual @synthesize, I believed Xcode would run the function for whatever property I add to the ViewController files. Thanks.